# Flask flash yields 404 error

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am trying to use `Flask's` `flash` functionality when a user click's a button on a form. The code correctly is identifying the button push as a `POST` request, yet the webpage yields a `404 error`. I have narrowed it down to `flash()` because without it, there is no `404 error`. What is the issue here?

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def meter_input():

    print request.method
    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.form['phone']
        flash('test')
    return render_template("input.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

input.html

```
<html>
<form  method="post">
<fieldset>

<div class="form-group">    
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value="" placeholder="">   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit"  id="update" value="Update Data"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<BR><BR>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flask.flash` apparently uses the `flask.session`. But the `flask.session` cannot be used without having defined a secret key for your app. You could have found this out if you started your server in debug mode (which you only should not do in production).

To start your server in debug mode use:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

To fix you actual problem define a secret key right after the creation of the `Flask` object

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Some secret string here"
```

I still don't know why you got a `404`. You should have gotten a `500` for `internal server error`

Comment: good suggestion. I'm mostly just playing around now so should probably just work in debug mode. Adding the secret key prevents the `404`, but the flash text never displays.

Comment: That's correct, but that  wasn't your question. If you want to know how to display the flashed messages take a look here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/